# Problem with Secured Access Signature any other alternative to share blob storage to users

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have created a blob storage at Azure and I want to share this container with my colleagues who may or may not have azure account and can upload files in this blob storage without providing access to resource groups or storage account. Is it possible with blob storage or there is any other alternative to do that where they can drop there files time to time and I can access them from my azure pipeline. I have tried Secured Acess Signature but it is not working may be I have less knowledge to do that. I have creatred SAS URL by clicking right click on container and shared the link with colleagues.

Comment: Here is the SAS for the File Share Storage and It is giving Authentication Error https://ssinsightstorage.file.core.windows.net/shared?st=2018-11-18T13%3A45%3A30Z&se=2018-11-20T13%3A45%3A00Z&sp=rwdl&sv=2018-03-28&sr=s&sig=NvDMqaIVb3x8A%2BRJ9VsvHzuiVjLwuLlXLeKZogw1EhI%3D

Comment: What is the error you're getting? How are your colleagues uploading the files?

Comment: That is my question. They simply copied the link in browser and get authentication error. I want a share location from where I can copy data to my sql database and my colleague can upload daily files. The colleague have very less technical knowledge. Simple upload using GUI will only work that too without providing much access to other resource groups